# Title with variable in jpGraph

Tags: jpgraph

How can I use a variable name in a title in jpGraph?

My code:

```
    $graph->title->Set('Geomagnetic Indices From "$OLD" to "$NEW"');
```

$OLD and $NEW are dates as strings that come from a search form.

Comment: `$graph->title->Set('Geomagnetic Indices From ' . $OLD . ' to ' . $NEW);`

Comment: Works perfect!  Just like PHP.  Thanks much.

Comment: Well it **IS** PHP after all.